# How to display a form list box as read-only or disabled with a selected index?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, webforms

The user sees a form with many controls, including a list box. He selects a single item in the list box and presses "submit".

In PHP I access $_POST[] and want to display the list box as read-only or disabled with his his selected item also selected. It should be read-only or disabled because I am showing him what he submitted and I don't want him changing it.

Can someone please give a very simple code example? (it has to work in MS IE (not my choice))

---

Edit for clarification:

There are two forms - a submission form in HTMl and a processing & acknowledgement form in PGP.

The first form offers a choice in many controls, the second verifies the input and, if valid, displays the input form again with a confirmation message. On this second form all fields must be static.

I have a problem only with a listbox (size >1, not combobox). I want to display ll of the initial choices but the user should not be allowed to change the selection, i.e, display all items, with one selected as either readonly or disabled.

Comment: Why display it in the list-box if you don't want them to change it? Why not just straight text? The problem with relying on readonly and disabled flags on an input is they can be too easily modified (Firebug) and can cause you headaches.

Comment: Perhaps the question was not clear, I have edited it. Thanks for commenting (+1)

Comment: @BrendanBullen - you might do this to create a consistent user experience.  Of course you verify the input is valid - you have to do this for all web input regardless of your presentation choices. If a user selected some options in a listbox originally, and now they need to review what was selected, using an identical display of that information requires the least amount of thought from the user to figure out what they are looking at.  If the UI doesn't let them change it, it won't matter if they Firebug-it and are disappointed with the outcome.  The UI communicated the intent well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="" method='post'>
<?php 
$disabled = isset($_POST['list'])?"disabled='disabled'":"";
?>
<select name='list' <?php echo $disabled;?> >
  <?php $selected = isset($_POST['list'])&&$_POST['list']=="1"?"selected='selected'":"";?>
  <option value="1" <?php echo $selected;?>>option1</option>
  <?php $selected = isset($_POST['list'])&&$_POST['list']=="2"?"selected='selected'":"";?>
  <option value="2" <?php echo $selected;?>>option2</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

i know i know... it looks horrible, there are cleaner ways to do it. but it works as an example

Comment: This does indeed work. The select is produced, visible and the selected items cannot be changed. The only downside of this is that when the form is submitted, the disabled inputs are not sent in the POST array. You could either populate additional hidden inputs detailing what was selected, or, have an onsubmit action on the form that enables the select before completing the submission...

Comment: Am I missing the point? I don't the fields to be disabled on the input form. The user can edit them there. But when he submits it I want to show the same form readonly with a confirmation message.